# cannot compile footstep_planner

Tags: roslaunch, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

```
I am a new user of ROS and I have tried to run the footstep_planner node and receive this message bellow:

    ERROR: cannot launch node of type [footstep_planner/footstep_planner_node]: can't locate node [footstep_planner_node] in package [footstep_planner]
```

This message occurred because the compilation was not successfully accomplished (can be seen in the end of the post).

To solve my problem, I have downloaded each octomap package from github and put the directories inside the stack but did not work.
I have tried to rosmake each octomap package, as well as the footstep_planner before, and then rosmake humanoid_navigation, but still did not work.
I don't know why, using ' sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-octomap*'  returns no package for me. Maybe solving this apt-get issue the problem can be solved? Any ideas?

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/2ca0d62902de0775b179cef924c9ec35

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133541/cannot-compile-footstep_planner/) by [borghetti](https://answers.ros.org/users/12471/borghetti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After fixing the apt-get repository setup, you can fix the newest errors (humanoid_nav_msgs and sbpl missing) by installing the required packages (via apt-get) `ros-groovy-humanoid-nav-msgs` and `ros-groovy-sbpl`.

Alternatively, you can download the source version and compile them in your workspace (but make sure that they are the correct versions for ROS groovy).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1